# Python : Scrape Game Names

Tags: python, web, python-requests, screen-scraping, analysis

I Am Having trouble Scraping names of games off a web page..
It is returning a blank array.. Once the name is scraped i want it to be written to a newly created Text file.. My Code should be below.. its nowhere near complete but im sure i will need a While condition..

```
def ScrapeK10():
siteToScrape = 'http://www.kiz10.com/new-games'
print '\n[!] Requesting Kiz10..'
kizReq = requests.get(siteToScrape)
print '\n[!] Scraping Newest Games...'
kizTree - html.fromstring(kizReq.content)
kizElement = kizTree.xpath('//strong[@class="bx-caption"]/text()')
print 'Latest Games : ', kizElement, '\n'
return
```

The problems im running into is im getting a blank array so im not sure if im actually scraping the site correctly or even using the correct xpath?

Still a little new to this.. Dont want to use Beautiful Soup nor do i want to use Scapy..

But my Goal is to scrape all games names in the web page i gave, And write them to a new file..

Comment: Please include any modules you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use regex?
Notice that all the game names are contained in a JavaScript object named 'itemsGame'.

Use regex to filter this out, then use regex again to split each line.

This should do it

```
def main():
    import re
    import requests
    url = "http://kiz10.com/index.php?page=newgames"
    raw = requests.get(url).content
    match = re.search("var itemsGame = \[(.*?)\];$", raw, re.M)
    for line in re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', match.group(1)):
        print(line.replace("'", "").split(",")[3].strip())
```

Alternatively you could just call eval() on the string from var itemsGame = 
to the next \n character.

Obviously though, eval is always dangerous and never really recommended

Comment: I Believe its in the Html isnt it? `<li class="it-glist" id="g-6430" data-idn="6430" onmouseover="_mhovcaption(6430,0)" onmouseleave="_mhovcaption(6430,1)"> <span class="mask-t">  <img src="http://cdn.kiz10.com/upload/thumbnails/thumbs/1475697830_five-fights-at-freddys.jpg">  <div class="fademask" style="display: block; left: 0px; top: 100%;"></div> </span>    <a href="http://kiz10.com/five-fights-at-freddys" class="item-mask"><strong class="bx-caption">Five Fights At Freddys</strong></a> <span class="etiqueta toll-reward" style="right:-1px;"></span></li>`

Comment: Ahh wait i guess its in both.. im still new to Python wasnt sure exactly what Regex did before i read a few things about it , but seen it was Bad practice to use , i will try this out , can you explain your code a little bit more though? i like to know what im doing instead of just copying someone elses code , i dont learn much that way

Comment: It Worked.. Thank you.. But i would still love an explanation Cause i have a few more sites i want to do this too and i want to learn more

Comment: So, basically, the exact data you need is contained in the itemsGame javascript array.

My method used regex to parse the string representation of it from the space character just after the equals sign to the end of the line.

Then use regex again to capture each subarray (itemsGame is an array of arrays).

Then we use pythons split method to split this into a list of strings, the 4th element (index 3) is the name of the game

Comment: Makes some sense lol.. I Need to learn more about the Split and strip methods